# Implementing onClick listener to multiple child layouts

Tags: android

I have an android XML structure as below. I would like when a child layout or its content (TextView or Image) is clicked, a clickListener to be trigered to do someAction. The problem is the layouts are randomly generated and are too many to have individual on click listener.

What is the best approach to solve this. So far i have set the child layouts to setClickable(true) and their children to setClickable(false)

```
        //MainLayoutContaining multiple children
        <Layout 1 >
            //This Layouts here are randomly generated programatically
            <Layout Child 1>
                <Textview />
                <ImageView />
                <Textview />
            </Layout Child 1>
            <Layout Child 2>
                <Textview />
                <ImageView />
                <Textview />
            </Layout Child 3>
                .
                .
                .
                .
            //End of Child Layouts
        </Layout 1>
```

**Edited**
I have a loop like this

```
        for(int i=0;i<newsFeedArray.length(); i++){
            LinearLayout a = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            a.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            a.setClickable(true);
            a.setOnClickListener(myListener);//New Code From Answer

            articleTitle.setText(articleItemTitle.toUpperCase());
            articleTitle.setClickable(false);   

            TextView articleBody = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            articleBody.setText(html2text(articleItemIntrotext));
            articleBody.setClickable(false);

            a.addView(articleTitle);
            a.addView(articleImage);
            a.addView(articleBody);
        }
```

I am now able to detect the onClick of each Layout. What now i want is to detect the id of that child layout that was clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a class `MyClickListener` which implements `OnClickListener` and inside the `onClick` method handle your calls, example:

```
public class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(v instance of TextView)
        // do what you want with textview
        // or another apporach 
        // detect which id had been clicked from your views 
    }
}
```

Then in your activity code set the `onClickListener` to `MyClickListener`

```
MyClickListener myListener = new MyClickListener();
someView.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

with a bit adjustments to the code this should work.

Another approach as @LunarWatcher suggested would be in the same class you can directly implement the `OnClickListener` interface and add the `onClick()` method inside. Both ways will work.

Comment: This can be done without a custom onClickListener class though. ANd it still assumes the views have the listener set

Comment: @LunarWatcher i dont get it, as he said `The problem is the layouts are randomly generated and are too many to have individual on click listener.` this means the listener is there but he needs to add `someAction` on the click which means he needs to either declare onClickListener to each view  `are too many to have individual on click listener.` which wont work for him. or to do it with a on class implementation.

Comment: You can basically copy-paste that method into the class and implement `OnClickListener` instead of creating an entire new class for one purpose

Comment: Well that's 100% correct, but then it depends on how much code you will have to have in one file which i (personally) don't like.

Comment: That's more a matter of preference (I prefer having it in one file). Either having it as a custom onClickListener or just implementing onCLickListener and adding the code in the same class works.

Comment: @YamenNassif i like the answer but how can i detect which id had been clicked from the views to enable someView.setOnClickListener(myListener);

Comment: you said you did this `setClickable(true)` so in same variables (objects) do the `setOnClickListener`

how are these views being generated?

Comment: you can set the id there
`articleTitle.setId(//int number)`
then `articleTitle.setOnClickListener()`

Comment: Thank You @YamenNassif that did it